# "The ordinal 344 could not be located in the dynamic link library"

Tags: c++, windows, runtime-error

I am trying to create a message box using [TaskDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760540.aspx). I am linking Comctl32.lib but the examples are not working for me. Everything compiles and links fine but instead of my message box showing up I get a different message box with the text "The ordinal 344 could not be located in the dynamic link library". The problem appears to occur when the application starts up, not when TaskDialog is called. Not linking Comctl32.lib will fix it but any call to `TaskDialog` will result in an undefined reference linker error.

I am using Visual Studio Community 2017 on Windows 10 64-bit. The application is being compiled as 64-bit.

Why do the examples not run?

Comment: This sounds like a mismatch between the library (.lib) you link with and the  DLL that is on the search path. Possibly different versions, debug vs. release builds or bitness ?

Comment: Present your [MCVE].

Comment: @BoundaryImposition I tried the example code at the bottom of the MSDN page I linked to. But as I said, I don't think it was the function call itself but rather linking the library. I don't know how I am supposed to include an example of that.

Comment: See the bottom: "DLL: Comctl32.dll (version 6)". You need to request version 6. [Enabling Visual Styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: think you not use manifest and as result build with old version *comctl32.dll* which not have this api. you need version 6

Answer (score 0):

TaskDialogs only exist in ComCtl32 v6.

There are two versions of ComCtl32.dll on Windows XP and later ([SxS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side-by-side_assembly)). v5.8x is the default, you need to opt-in to get v6 because of possible incompatibility's with the new Themes/Visual Styles. Most new features and controls have only been added to v6.

To get v6 you must [add a manifest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175(v=vs.85).aspx#no_extensions) to your application. It is recommended that you embed the manifest in the applications resources but you can also use a external manifest; just name the XML file `yourappname.exe.manifest`.